# Displaying data in Excel's stack column chart

Tags: excel

[image]

I have data that looks like this and want to display them using the stack column chart. I want it to look like the second picture, but when I click stack column, it appears as the first picture.

[image]

so I want

1) the names to point to the colored area using arrows

2) display the individual values in the colored areas

3) display the total value too.

How do I do this?

Comment: The arrows will have to be manual as this is not normal practice (the whole point of color coding is to reference the legend). To display the %, just add data label. To display the total, add a 2nd axis and you can use a line (with no color fill to hide it) with a data label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well part of what you desire can be achieved. The arrows, not what I know. Don't forget that the Excel charts actually is quite limited...

But we can do some stuff :)

**Final result:**

[image]

**Step-by-Step:**

Select ALL of your data as in the picture and create your table:

[image]

Select one part of the stacked bars, I selected the blue (you can see small circles) then right click and choose "Add Data Labels". Do this for ALL of your categories:

[image]

Time to format data labels. Right Click on one data labels and click "Format Data Labels".

[image]

Instead of arrows, we can choose "Series Name". Do the same step for all of your bars.

[image]

Time to manipulate the Total. We right click on the total "blue" block and choose "Fill". Then click "No Fill". You can now click in the data table and add "=". You can also move the label around. A little line will appear (linked to your "hidden" bar, but you can delete that line.)

[image]

Final step, at the legend. Click "Total" so you select it (see my picture). Then click "Del" on your keyboard.

[image]